# OpsHub VS Migration asking fro administrative permissions and I am the Visual Studio Admin

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, opshub

I keep getting Error: 1) Administrative Permissions Needed for Logged In user in Visual Studio Online.

I am the VS online Site Administrator. I double checked and I am a member of the Project Collection Service Account. Any ideas?

I tried reinstalling, I tried deleting and re adding the TFS server connection

Comment: Did you ever get this working? We're having the same issue. The user running the migration is the user who created the VSO site so she is the owner. She is a member of Project Collection Administrators and the Project Administrators group for the project.

What else can we do to get more information?

Thanks, Bill

Comment: It turns out she didn't add herself to the Project Collection Service Accounts group. This is in the instructions but it doesn't work if you go to groups and try to add the user. You have to go to the user and join a group. She added herself to all of the other groups instead. It would be a good idea to add this to the docs for OpsHub.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please check if user is under **Project Collection Administrators** as well **Project Collection Service Accounts**  group or not. For more information please refer following guide to check you have correct group privileges for the account you are using from TFS Utility.

http://www.opshub.com/ohrel/Resources/TFS/permissions.php?page=admin

Let us know in case if it does not work for you.

Thanks,
OpsHub

Comment: Yes the user is executing the migration is part of this group. Are there any logs that could tell me anything else?

Comment: Please send us the logs created by the utility from the following location "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs" to ovsmu@opshub.com and we can deduce the actual reason of this error.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else should come across this, you need to RDP onto your TFS (on-premise) box. Open a command prompt. **C**hange **D**irectory (cd) to the Program Files folder where TFS was installed into. See my example below:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools"
```

Within the directory above (path may be different for your TFS install), there should be a tfssecurity.exe file. You need to run that using the following command (within the same command prompt window you ran the above command):

```
tfssecurity /g+ "Project Collection Service Accounts" n:"{VISUAL STUDIO ONLINE ACCOUNT EMAIL ADDRESS}" /collection:"{FULL URL TO YOUR VS SUBSCRIPTION}"
```

Don't forget to replace the values within braces ({VALUE}) with the values applicable to your accounts!